# Laravel SQL Server Query Syntax

Tags: sql-server, laravel, t-sql

I need some help regarding the syntax of a query I am unable to run.
It is a SQL Server query I can run on a SQL Server, which I tried to implement in a laravel db::select statement, without success.

The problem that arises is the escape characters and column names
Here's an example:

```
DB::connection('con')->select('SELECT a."First Name", b."Last Name",  DATEADD (
        minute,
        a."Birthday Date",
        DATEADD (day, a."Birthday Time", '1899-12-31')
    ) as 'Birthday', FROM
    DATABASE..[PERSONS] a
    LEFT JOIN DATABASE..[PERSONNELDATA] b ON b."First Name" = a."First Name"');
```

Please do not pay attention to the logic as I rewrote this on the fly to make a simplified example. The original query which cannot be posted is too long on top of that.

Whenever I try to run this query I get a couple of errors regarding "Unexpected ')' or Unexpected ' ) and so on.. how can I run this query, that is capable of being run in SQL Server Management Studio?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is that _the exact same query_ as you're running in SQL Server? If so, consider changing all your quoted identifiers to be consistent e.g. use all `[]` or `""` and not a mix of the two

Comment: what you get from this `DATEADD (
        minute,
        a."Birthday Date",
        DATEADD (day, a."Birthday Time", '1899-12-31')
    )`

Comment: i said do not pay attention to the logical aspect of the query. :) I dont know what you will get from this with real data, try it out yourself in the sql server studio manager

Comment: Added an answer based on my earlier comment 

Answer (score 1):

Laravel comes with a DB::getQueryLog() function. You could use that to retrieve the SQL statement you just used and put it in your SQL tool to find the differences between your query there and what the DB facade produces.

Comment: nice idea, but it was actually only the different identifiers as gvee said. Thanks for you help though! I appreciate it very much

Comment: Fair enough. Let's hope this helps someone someday though.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing quoted identifiers (see [Database Identifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-identifiers) in the manual).

You are using both `[]` and `""`.

Change them to be consistent throughout your query, and then see how Laravel gets on!

Swapping them all to double quotes, for instance, would yield:

```sql
SELECT a."First Name"
     , b."Last Name"
     , DATEADD(minute, a."Birthday Date", DATEADD(day, a."Birthday Time", '1899-12-31')) AS "Birthday"
FROM  DATABASE.."PERSONS" AS a
 LEFT
  JOIN DATABASE.."PERSONNELDATA" AS b
    ON b."First Name" = a."First Name"
;
```